# no method error in Rails 3 with Devise and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

I have a problem with my Rails application, which I deploy to Heroku.
As I do POST on my Club resource it says:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"MqScpac6l9MMHdPBehqfq0mTwLCCZq2dlZLVY6wt+ow=", 
"club"=>    {"name"=>"Grün Weiß Club im PSV Kiel"}, "commit"=>"absenden"}
2012-12-31T03:10:49+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id=' for #  <Club:0x000000061269b0>):
2012-12-31T03:10:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-31T03:10:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-31T03:10:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/clubs_controller.rb:47:in `create'
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'name ASC'
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships, :order => 'name ASC'
  validates :name, presence: true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

and the controllers create action like this:

```
def create
  @club = Club.new(params[:club])
  @club.user_id = current_user.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @club.save
      format.html { redirect_to @club, notice: 'Club was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @club, status: :created, location: @club }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @club.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The authentication is done by the Devise gem. What additionally confuses me is, that if I run the rails console on heroku it says:

```
irb(main):001:0> Club
=> Club(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer)
```

So even the DB should be right. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try running `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Do you get the same error locally?

Comment: I had a similar issue today, even after migrating the heroku db. I did a "heroku restart" and that fixed it.

Comment: For those having the same issue, try "heroku restart".

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the controller and see if it works:

```
@club = current_user.clubs.build params[:club]
```

instead of

```
@club = Club.new(params[:club])
@club.user_id = current_user.id
```

Make sure `User` includes `has_many :clubs`, and then you can get rid of `attr_accessible :user_id`

Comment: I just did this, but it didn't worked. The Club was created properly, so with no error, but the user_id isn't set at all, it's still nil. Do you have another hint for me?

Comment: can i see the User model? `user.rb`

Comment: ah that's why. You have to decide if you want `user.clubs` to return the clubs the user belongs to or the clubs the user owns

Comment: I really don't know why, but as I refactored it a bit it worked.